# PHP: regexp and specific tags stripping

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am looking for a way to strip all anchor tags also i want everything from ',' to `<br>` to be removed but `<br>` should remain thr.

dirty input:

```
Abstractor HLTH<br>
Account Representative, Major <a href="#P">P</a><br>
Accountant <a href="#NP">NP</a>, <a href="#M">M</a>, <a href="#REA">REA</a>, <a href="#SKI">SKI</a><br>
```

it should be like:

```
Abstractor HLTH<br>
Account Representative<br>
Accountant <br>
```

please help!

--
following is the dirty text:

```
$str = sprintf('

Abstractor HLTH<br>
Account Representative, Major <a href="#P">P</a><br>

Accountant <a href="#NP">NP</a>, <a href="#M">M</a>, <a href="#REA">REA</a>, <a href="#SKI">SKI</a><br>
Accountant, Cost I & II (See Cost Accountant I, II) <a href="#FR">FR</a><br>
Accountant, General <a href="#G">G</a><br>
Accountant, General I (Junior) (See General Accountant) <a href="#FR">FR</a>, <a href="#O/G">O/G</a>, <a href="#W">W</a><br>

Accountant, General II (Intermediate) (See General Accountant) <a href="#FR">FR</a>, <a href="#O/G">O/G</a>, <a href="#W">W</a>, <a href="#HA">HA</a> <br>
Accountant, General III (Senior) (See General Accountant) <a href="#FR">FR</a>, <a href="#O/G">O/G</a>, <a href="#W">W</a> <br>

');
```

Comment: first line to read as: 
I am looking for a way to strip all anchor tags also i want everything from ',' to linebreak tag to be removed but line break should remain thr.

Comment: isn't any other way without using HTML Purifier? !

Comment: Try my answer and see if it works for you.

Comment: note: all lines are in single string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it's bad to use regex to deal with HTML strings, but assuming all your links are formed like that then using `preg_replace()` *shouldn't* pose problems. Try this

```
// Removes all links
$str = preg_replace("/<a href=\"#([A-Z\\/]+?)\">\\1<\\/a>(?:, )?/i", "", $str);

// Strip the comma and everything from the comma
// to the next <br> in the line
$str = preg_replace("/,(.*?)(?=<br>)/i", "", $str);
```

To the other answers suggesting `strip_tags()`: it won't erase text contained by a pair of HTML tags that it strips. For example

```
Accountant <a href="#NP">NP</a>
```

becomes

```
Accountant NP
```

which isn't quite what the OP wants.

Comment: it ignores every br till end which is not desired.. 

your code gives this output:
Abstractor HLTH
Account Representative

ignoring 'Accountant' because its between "," and the last br

Comment: @ehmad1: Do you mean all three lines are in a single string?

Comment: @ehmad1: Give me a while more.

Comment: @ehmad1: Could you paste that `sprintf()` part into your question? I'm not exactly going to type that all out to test...

Comment: @ehmad1: I updated my code too. Can you try it and see if you get the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise using **HTML Purifier** http://htmlpurifier.org/

It is fairly simple to set up, has an excellent reputation and extremely powerful.

Answer (score 0):

[strip-tags()](http://php.net/strip-tags) for the tags, [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) with [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) for the other thing.

Comment: strip_tags **ONLY** allow certain tags to remain, but OP want reverse way

Comment: Oh, yes, right. Leave the answer anyway, maybe someone is interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is your friend. It has flexible options, and is very sophisticated. Doing such things with str_replace or regular expressions is **wrong**.

Comment: I did not downvote, but why is there an upvote for one HTML Purifier answer and a downvote for this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
$clean_string = strip_tags($original_string, '<br>');
```

This will strip everything apart from br tags.

As KingCrunch says, `str_replace` and `strpos` for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

[strip_tags](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) has a second argument which allows you to supply a string of allowable tags. It will strip all tags except the ones you supply:

```
$string = strip_tags($string, '<br>'); // will leave <br>-tags in place
```